# how to iterate json object in c#

Tags: c#

I have a JSON object in c#. I wants to iterate it in c#. All properties in object are dynamic. In following code tr5, tr5td7, tr6, tr6td4 are dynamic name, it can be change in another object. so please help me.

```
  "trList": {
"tr5": {
  "tdList": {
    "tr5td7": {
      "td": {
        "outcomesName": "Weight (kg) Simvastatin",
        "group": {
          "groups": "Entry",
          "dosage": "",
          "n": ""
        },
        "values": [
          {
            "type": "Mean",
            "symbolType": "x¯",
            "value": "78.4"
          },
          {
            "type": "SE",
            "symbolType": "S",
            "value": "3.1"
          }
        ],
        "pattern": {
          "arr": [
            {
              "values": "78.4",
              "pattern": "number",
              "type": "Mean",
              "symbolType": "x¯"
            },
            {
              "values": "3.1",
              "pattern": "number",
              "type": "SE",
              "symbolType": "S"
            }
          ],
          "pat": "number-separator-number-separator-",
          "tdId": "tr5td7"
        },
        "note": "",
        "outcomesNote": "",
        "groupsNote": ""
      }
    },
  }
 }
     "tr6": {
  "tdList": {
    "tr6td4": {
      "td": {
        "outcomesName": "Height (kg) Simvastatin",
        "group": {
          "groups": "Entry",
          "dosage": "",
          "n": ""
        },
        "values": [
          {
            "type": "Mean",
            "symbolType": "x",
            "value": "70.4"
          },
          {
            "type": "SE",
            "symbolType": "S",
            "value": "5"
          }
        ],
        "pattern": {
          "arr": [
            {
              "values": "70.4",
              "pattern": "number",
              "type": "Mean",
              "symbolType": "x"
            },
            {
              "values": "5",
              "pattern": "number",
              "type": "SE",
              "symbolType": "S"
            }
          ],
          "pat": "number-separator-number-separator-",
          "tdId": "tr6td4"
        },
        "note": "",
        "outcomesNote": "",
        "groupsNote": ""
      }
    },
  }
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your `dynamic` object is effectively just a `Dictionary<string, object>`, so you can cast it as such e.g.

```
IDictionary<string, object> dict = jsonObject;
foreach (var item in dict)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", item.Key, item.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use JSON.Net.

```
dynamic d = JObject.Parse("{number:1000, str:'string', array: [1,2,3,4,5,6]}");

Console.WriteLine(d.number);
Console.WriteLine(d.str);
Console.WriteLine(d.array.Count);
```